# Mysql and PHP select Join Count

Tags: php, mysql

I have already searched for possible answers but did not find any who helped me further.

I have two tables. One named users, where the user details are saved like: Name, ID, etc.
Second one is a table where the payments are stored.

Payments:

```
payment_id
date
amount
user_id
completed
```

Now I try to get all the payments of a user:

```
SELECT COUNT(amount) FROM ...
```

I already have tried this but did'nt gave me the right amount that has been paid.

```
SELECT 
    g.name, 
    g.user_id, 
    COUNT(m.amount) AS totalAmount
FROM users AS g
LEFT JOIN payments AS m ON g.user_id = m.user_id
GROUP BY g.user_id
```

Comment: Use sum instead of count

Comment: What results are you getting as opposed to the desired results; you didn't say.

Comment: Thanks for not answering to comments.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JoeTaras. I used sum and it worked.

Comment: Sorry @FunkFortyNiner. What I did receive was the x-times there was a payment in the mysql database for the user. I used sum and all was ok. Thanks for the help and the late reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want... `SUM(m.amount)` instead of `COUNT(m.amount)` ?

`COUNT(m.amount)` gives you the number of rows that were aggregated (that means the total number of payments).

`SUM(m.amount)` is the cumulated value of field `m.amount`, that is the total amount.